# Equation with integral, numerical solution

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I would like to solve this equation, but I don't know how to do that.

The equation is: $$ A\int_0^{\infty}x^3e^{Ax-x^2/2}dx=3\int_0^{\infty}x^2e^{Ax-x^2/2}dx.$$

I would like to know the value of $A$ (or just an numerical approximation).

I don't know how to solve the problem or which program I can use to get an explicit solution. I tried Matlab and Mathematica, but I didn't get a result with any of them. It could be that I entered the problem in the program incorrectly.

Comment: Have a look at the edit in my answer

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot since I have other similar examples to solve.

Comment: I cannot resist equations ! What is the most difficult ?

Comment: Numerically  in Mathematica  try the code:`NSolve[A*Integrate[x^3 Exp[A x - x^2/2], {x, 0, Infinity}] == 
   3*Integrate[x^2 Exp[A x - x^2/2], {x, 0, Infinity}] && 
  1 < A < 2, A, Reals]`

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I asked for one example to be solved to know how to solve this problem. This was just one of my cases. Lets say that $G_{\nu}(y)=\int_0^{\infty}u^{\nu -1}e^{-yu-u^2/2}du \text{ and } F_{\nu}(y)=G_{\nu}(-y)$. I need to solve $AF_{2n+1}'(A)=(2n+1)F_{2n+1}(A)$ for $n$ natural. I asked a question above where $n=1$. I have also equations like $A(G'_q(A)+F'_q(A))=q(G_q(A)+F_q(A))$ where $q>0$. And also equation $AG'_3(-A)+G_3(-A)=0$. I need to present some exaples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maple says $A \approx 1.297166$ .  Evaluating the integrals symbolically, there are $\operatorname{erf}$ functions in there, so Maple cannot solve explicitly.

[image: A]

Graph of $\int_0^{\infty}(3x^2-Ax^3)e^{Ax-x^2/2}dx$ .

Answer (score 2):

$$\text{lhs}=A \left(\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \left(A^2+3\right) e^{\frac{A^2}{2}} A
   \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{A}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+1\right)+A^2+2\right)$$
$$\text{rhs}=3 \left(\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \left(A^2+1\right) e^{\frac{A^2}{2}}
   \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{A}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+1\right)+A\right)$$

Make a series expansion around $A=\sqrt 2$ and use series reversion; the very first estimate is
$$A_0= \sqrt 2+\frac{e \sqrt{\pi } (\text{erfc}(1)-2)-2}{3 \sqrt{2} \left(3 e \sqrt{\pi
   } (\text{erf}(1)+1)+2\right)}=1.32467$$ The first iteration of Newton method gives $A_1=1.29898$ and the next is $1.29717$

**Edit**

A much better approximation (first iteration of Halley method) is
$$A_0= \sqrt 2-\frac{6 \sqrt{2} \left(3 e^2 \pi  \alpha ^2+8 e \sqrt{\pi }
   \alpha +4\right)}{265 e^2 \pi  \alpha ^2+268 e \sqrt{\pi }   \alpha +52}$$ where $\alpha=(\text{erf}(1)+1)$. Numerically, this is $1.30087$.

Same with Householder method
$$A_0=\sqrt 2-\frac{3 \left(e \sqrt{\pi } \alpha  \left(265 e^2 \pi  \alpha
   ^2+798 e \sqrt{\pi } \alpha +588\right)+104\right)}{\sqrt{2}
   \left(e \sqrt{\pi } \alpha  \left(5735 e^2 \pi  \alpha ^2+7338
   e \sqrt{\pi } \alpha +2004\right)-200\right)}$$ which is $1.29747$.

For different orders of Newton-like methods, the numerical values are

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & \text{approximation} & \text{method} \\
 2 &  1.3246710 & \text{Newton}\\
 3 &  1.3008695 & \text{Halley}\\
 4 &  1.2974683 & \text{Householder}\\
 5 &  1.2971820 & \text{no name}\\
 6 &  1.2971669 & \text{no name}\\
 7 &  1.2971664 & \text{no name}\\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Since you use Mathematica, I give you the syntax

`F=A*(-1+A^2)+(-3+A^4)*E^(A^2/2)*Sqrt[Pi/2]*(1+Erf[ASqrt[2]])`
`P[n_]:=Solve[Numerator[PadeApproximant[F,{A,Sqrt[2],{1, n}}]]==0,A]`